# d3js gantt chart with date/time scale at the top and current day blue line

Tags: d3.js, timeline, gantt-chart

I am working on a d3js gantt chart - and I want to enhance this chart code so that it can incorporate a date/time scale at the top that morphs on view -- and also add a blue line that indicates the current date/time(moves - in real time?). I think also the lane height is not correct - and its a bit difficult to adjust the height of the lanes - add gutter if desired in the future design. There may be redundant grid lines in the scrubber area.

//current design
[image]

//new concept
[image]

//latest version
https://jsfiddle.net/2mvhjr7z/2/

//html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <title>Gantt chart with D3.js</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

      <div 
           class="timelinechart" 
           data-role="timelinechart" 
           data-width=500 
           data-height=300 
           data-data=""
           >
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

//css

```
        body {
          background: #eeeeee;
        }

        #holder {
          overflow: hidden;
        }

/*
.chart {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
*/

.timelinechart{
    /*width:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.timelinechart svg{
    width:100%;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}

.timelinechartg{

}

.mini text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;  
}

.main text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;  
}

.miniItem {
    /*fill: darksalmon;*/
    stroke-width: 6;    
}

.miniItem.future{
    fill: #448875;
}
text.future {
    fill: #f7b363;
}


.brush .extent {
    stroke: #b6b8b9;
    fill: #57585b;
    fill-opacity: .365;
    stroke-width: .2;
}

.laneImg{
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

//js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  var $this = $('.timelinechart');

  var w = $this.data("width");
  var h = $this.data("height");

  var data = [
    {
      "label": "Argentina",
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355752840000}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Bolivia",
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355752900000}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Brazil",
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": 1355752900000, "ending_time": 1355752935000}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Canada",
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": 1355753000000, "ending_time": 1355753500000}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Chile",
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": 1355753700000, "ending_time": 1355754000000}
      ]
    }
  ];


  var lanes = [];
  var times = [];

  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    lanes.push(value.label);
    $.each(value.times, function(i, v) {
      v["lane"] = index;
    });
    times.push(value.times);
  });

  var laneLength = lanes.length;
  var items = [].concat.apply([], times);

  $.each(items, function(i, v) {
    v["id"] = i;
  });

  var timeBegin = d3.min(items, function(d) { return d["starting_time"]; });
  var timeEnd = d3.max(items, function(d) { return d["ending_time"]; });

  var m = [25, 80, 15, 105], //top right bottom left
      w = w - m[1] - m[3],
      h = h - m[0] - m[2],
      miniHeight = 50,//laneLength * 12 + 50,
      mainHeight = h - miniHeight - 50;


  //scales
  var x =  d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, w])
  .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd]);
  var x1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, w]);
  var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, mainHeight])
  .domain([0, laneLength]);
  var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, miniHeight])
  .domain([0, laneLength]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
  .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d));


  var scaleFactor = (1/(timeEnd - timeBegin)) * (w);

  var chartWidth = w + m[1] + m[3];
  var chartHeight = h + m[0] + m[2];

  var chart = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", chartWidth)
  .attr("height", chartHeight)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+chartWidth+" "+chartHeight)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "timelinechartg");

  chart.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", mainHeight);

  var main = chart.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", mainHeight)
  .attr("class", "main");

  var mini = chart.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + m[0]) + ")")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", miniHeight)
  .attr("class", "mini");


  var gX = chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + miniHeight) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

  //background colors
  function colores_background(n) {
    var colores_g = ["#f8dd2f", "#e9168a", "#448875", "#2b2d39", "#c3bd75", "#1b91dc"];
    return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
  }

  //foreground colors
  function colores_foreground(n) {
    var colores_g = ["#553814", "#311854", "#f7b363", "#c12f39", "#89191d", "#2b2d39"];
    return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
  }

  //main lanes and texts
  main.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
    .data(items)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
    .attr("x2", w)
    .attr("y2", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
    .attr("stroke", "lightgray")

  var defs = main.append('svg:defs');

  main.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
    .data(lanes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .attr("x", (-m[1] + 10))
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return y1(i + .5);
  })
    .attr("dy", ".5ex")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("class", "laneText");

  //mini lanes and texts
  mini.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
    .data(items)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return y2(d.lane);
  })
    .attr("x2", w)
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return y2(d.lane);
  })
    .attr("stroke", "lightgray");



  var itemRects = main.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");


mini.append('rect')
  .attr("class", "miniBar")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", 30);





  var brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
  .on("brush", brushed);

  mini.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", 1)
    .attr("height", miniHeight - 1);

  function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection;
    var timeSelection = selection.map(x.invert, x);
    //console.log("selection: " + selection);
    //console.log("start: " + timeSelection[0]);
    //console.log("end: " + timeSelection[1]);

    var rects;
    var labels;
    var minExtent = timeSelection[0];
    var maxExtent = timeSelection[1];  

    var visItems = items.filter(function(d) {return d.starting_time <  maxExtent && d.ending_time > minExtent;});

    //mini.select(".brush")
    //.call(brush.extent([minExtent, maxExtent]));        

    x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);      

    //update main item rects
    rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
      .data(visItems, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);});

    rects.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + .8;})
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

    rects.exit().remove();

    //update the item labels
    labels = itemRects.selectAll("text")
      .data(visItems, function (d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent) + 2);});

    labels.enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
      .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent));})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane + .5);})
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colores_foreground(d.lane);
    })
      .attr("text-anchor", "start");

    labels.exit().remove();
  }

});
```

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaletime  -- some time scale morphs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added gutters. You can change the number to change the gutter ratio.

I added another axis bound to `x1` scale,

```js
var xAxisTop = d3.axisBottom(xTop)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
    .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")(d));
```

and it is called in `brushed` as the following.

```js
gXTop.call(xAxisTop);
```

If there's something I missed, or anything else you want added, please, comment.

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KgomDr/cs3jo41b/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206489/discussion-on-answer-by-hurried-helpful-d3js-gantt-chart-with-date-time-scale-at).

Comment: why -- its useful research -- latest code base with auto scrub -- you want to try and integrate this solution into your code base? clean up the functions etc. https://jsfiddle.net/m6ueL79o/3/

Comment: you able to write any more comments as to how the key features work. Should xTop -- be x2 - and if so why isn't?

Comment: There are three x scales: `x`, `xTop`, and `x1`. `xTop` and `x1` always have identical domains and ranges, but `x1` is a `d3.scaleLinear` and `xTop` is a `d3.scaleTime`. Therefore, they are not interchangeable. `xTop` could be renamed to `x2`, but `xTop` is a better name for code readability and reusability. Also, `x2` and `x1` are the names of common svg attributes, so these names might cause confusion to people not familiar with the code base.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle